# python: converting from unknown char encoding (assume iso-8859-1) to unicode

Tags: python, character-encoding

I'm decoding an xml file with xml.etree and one of the elements contains this string:

```
ExÃ©cutive
```

I tried pretty much everything to figure out how to tranform it to its real value:

```
Exécutive
```

I tried the following:

```
>>> s = 'Ã©'

>>> s
'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9'

>>> print s
Ã©

>>> type(s)
<type 'str'>

>>> s.decode('iso-8859-1')
u'\xc3\x83\xc2\xa9'

>>> print( s.decode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8'))
ÃÂ©

>>> print( s.decode('utf-8'))
Ã©
```

I'm kind of lost here with these encodings. Anyone for a little help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like you need to decode utf-8.

Comment: your avatar says you're Jeff Atwood's lost young anime brother.

Comment: The data looks like UTF-8 encoded string misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @others: I updated the question with the decode. It doesn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is apparently UTF-8 encoded data (e.g., “é” is two bytes) misinterpreted as ISO-8859-1. For the test case, the following produces the output “Exécutive”:

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
s = 'ExÃ©cutive'
print s.decode('utf-8')
```

In processing the XML file, you probably just need to read it as UTF-8.